# Microvolts on Steam came with 'XTrap'. Is it safe?

Tags: steam, microvolts, xtrap

Is XTrap Safe? My little brother downloaded Microvolts surge from steam and got it. Is it a virus? Can it get me a virus? All I know that it is anti-cheat, but that's it. Will it add tracking cookies, or put a trojan on his computer? Anything bad about it?

Comment: It is an anti-cheat agent, not a trojan. However, it seems that people do find it difficult to get rid off after you uninstall the game that it was bundled with.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LHRtW.jpg) - It's not a trap

Comment: I wouldn't think its dangerous. Valve wouldn't put anything malicious on their servers.

Comment: Looking at the duplicated question, it actually looks like X-TRAP can be quite nasty. It's not malware, but it is very invasive. I suggest reading the answers in the duplicated question.